# Magento 2 : Admin URL Redirects to Search Results Page

Tags: database, magento2.4, magento-admin

When I try going to the admin panel of my local environment of Magento 2.4 (Enterprise) (admin URL is `http://{unsecure_domain}/admin`) It redirects me to a secure previous domain as if I was doing a search with the following URL:

```
https://{secure_domain}/catalogsearch/result/?q=admin+admin+index+index+key+{generated_key}
```

This is what I've tried:

1. In the database I set my local domain `http://{unsecure_domain}/` for `web/unsecure/base_url` and for `web/secure/base_url`
2. Run the following commands in order:

   ```
   $ bin/magento setup:di:compile
   $ bin/magento setup:upgrade
   $ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   $ bin/magento cache:clean
   $ bin/magento cache:flush
   ```

However, I still get redirected to that URL above. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. So after looking deeply into `core_config_data` I found that there were more rows pertaining to `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` And, when I select them all, I found the old domain entries. So in total I had to change about 8 rows with the new domain. I think this is because we have two additional store views with different languages. Here are some steps that might help achieve it:

Enter the following command:

```
mysql -u <$database_user> -p <$database_name>
```

Enter your password when prompted.

Access the database using the following command:

```
use <database_name>
```

Execute:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';
```

This will display the current base_urls set in Magento.

To change the base URLs, execute:

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://{unsecure_domain}/' where path = 
'web/unsecure/base_url';

update core_config_data set value = 'http://{unsecure_domain}/' where path = 
'web/secure/base_url';
```

I hope it helps!